# Автоматически запускающиеся скрипты

Tags: cron, скрипт, php

Всем известен Крон, который по расписанию будет выполнять скрипты, какие вам нужно. Но у меня немного задача отличается и думаю, просто кроном тут не обойтись..
Есть сайт с зарегистрированными пользователями. Если на сайте никто не залогинен, то и крона не надо - никакого расписания запуска скриптов не надо. Сайт стоит без изменений
Но после того как кто-то залогинился и грубо говоря нажал кнопку, должна включиться последовательность запуска разных скриптов. Занять эти скрипты могут от пары минут до пары часов, вот только нюанс в том, что юзер может даже выйти с сайта, закрыть все страницы, а вот скрипты должны продолжить свое выполнение.
Подскажите пожалуйста, кто знает, как такое можно реализовать?

Уточню. Скриптов может быть от штук десяти до сотен и тысяч. И Главный критерий - каждый следующий скрипт должен запускаться сразу после окончания работы предыдущего. А если ставить Крон, то поскольку я знаю, минимальный интервал запуска скриптов у него 1 минута, придется постоянно ждать - не хорошо :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

крон:)
Крон каждый, скажем, час запускает некий скрипт.

Пользователь жмет кнопку, в БД появляется строчка с заданием/строчки с заданиями.

Тот самый некий скрипт лезет в БД, ищет невыполненные задания и стартует их полностью или частично, после чего засыпает.
Задание пишет в БД выполнилось ли оно или нет. Если да - оно больше не запускается, если нет - в базе об этом запись.

Если "тот самый скрипт" не нашел ни одного задания, он засыпает.

Comment: Уточню. Скриптов может быть от штук десяти до сотен и тысяч. И Главный критерий - каждый следующий скрипт должен запускаться сразу после окончания работы предыдущего. А если ставить Крон, то поскольку я знаю, минимальный интервал запуска скриптов у него 1 минута, придется постоянно ждать - не хорошо :(

Comment: Тысячи скриптов - это не есть гут. В любом случае, особенно, если они работают одновременно. =)  
Каждый следующий может попытаться запустить соседа, если общее время исполнения позволяет(30с или какое там у вас ограничение). Если не позволяет - см выше.

Comment: Ну.. Скрипт на самом деле один и тот же, просто в него поступают разные парамерты. Выглядеть это должно так, как будто этот скрипт выполняет некий пошаговый туториал, и от шага к шагу пауз быть не должно. Запускать этот скрипт однажды, чтоб он по циклу выполнял каждый шаг тоже немного стремно - работать то он может и пару часов - не видал еще такого на своем опыте. Поэтому, думаю, лучше последовательно эти "шаги" запускать, но вот как это сделать без пауз...?

Comment: Без пауз это можно сделать, рекурсивно вызывая curl, file_get_contents или include. Ровно как и в цикле. Сигналом к останвке, как я уже писал, должно стать время. 30 секунд поработал, 30 отдохнул.
За 30 секунд можно перелопатить несколько гигабайт информации, если че, при правильном подходе.

Пример для довольно долгой операции - развертывание БД из дампа:

читаете содержимое файла построчно. В цикле запоминаете номер строки. 
если время кончается, записываете номер и имя файла. По крону начинаете уже не с начала, а с этого номера.

Comment: Понятно. Ну на этом, наверное, и остановимся. Буду пробовать. Большое спасибо за советы!

Answer (score 0):

Есть доп таблица, файл и т.д. В неё(него) пиши старт своих скриптов, может это просто 1 единичка.

А крон все равно запускать придется чтобы тот смотрел на этот файл, и если есть запись "1" то выполняй свои команды сколько угодно раз.